# How do I tail a log file and keep tailing it when the latest one changes date?

Tags: logs, tail

I'm using RHEL 4.

The normal `tail -F file_name*.log` doesn't update when the time flips over to 0000.

Here's what I've tried so far from searching the web, both of which try to use nested `tail`:

`tail -F $(ls -tr file_name*.log | tail -n 1)`

`tail -F $(fine . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail n 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2-)`

None of these flip over to new files. Plain old `tail -F file_name*.log` works in my small test cases (while the 2 above don't), but it doesn't work when I'm tailing a real log file.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are trying to continually tail a file despite a log-rotate taking effect, `tail -F filename.log` is what you want.  I am not following what you are trying to do with all of the extra nesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't (can't) work - the sub-shells you're using to determine the latest file only get executed once.   The glob won't work because the shell evaluates the wild-card only ONCE.

One way to deal with it would be to use 'watch' to run the whole thing, but that would hack up the output every so many seconds.

Comment: Ah, I'll just go about writing some script for it then. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`tail` monitors a single file, or at most a set of files that is determined when it starts up. In the command `tail -F file_name*.log`, first the shell expands the wildcard pattern, then `tail` is called on whatever file(s) exist at the time.

To monitor a set of files based on wildcards, you can use [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

```
multitail -iw 'file_name*.log' 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to have to write something to follow tail. Or configure your system to not roll logs (or that log) at midnight. Either way, the filehandle of the tailed logfile is reset when it's rolled.