# Using tail to follow daily log file in Bash

Tags: logs, tail

I have a task to use a bash script to monitor a couple of log files named with the current day, eg. YYYY-MM-DD.log.

(1) I used `tail -f` to follow the file but unable to deal file rotation.

Even if using `tail -F $FILENAME`, I can only follow the log for 24 hours max and need to restart again.

What I wish to accomplish is to have something like `tail -F $CURRENTDATE`, so I can leave it running forever and every midnight It will switch to follow the new log file named with current date.

But it seems the variable `$CURRENTDATE` is not dynamic. Is there another way to do this without `crontab`'ing the script every 24 hours? Maybe set a symbolic file or something?

(2) Meanwhile, if `tail -f` is used, what signal will it return if the file it follows is missing or changes its name? How can I trap the exceptions during execution.

Comment: Maybe you should check this answer. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53704/41104

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately there is no solution available.

Comment: I am looking into a solution provided by a Perl script from http://search.cpan.org/~mgrabnar/File-Tail-0.99.3/Tail.pm#___top.

Comment: Actually, just so slm answer has validity, what process generate these logs files? And can you make it so it uses a single name instead and the rotate job add the dates?

Comment: It will be much better but I am afraid it is beyond my reach :(

Comment: What is creating the log file?

Comment: Syslog-ng generates the log file. Unfortunately amending the logging format is out of the question. What I am going to do, is just to crontab a script calling the `tail -f` script at 00:00 hours and sleep for 86400s then `kill -TERM -$$`, so it runs again with a new $CURRENTDATE. Please commend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$CURRENTDATE` isn't dynamic the way that you think. That variable gets expanded when the `tail -F $CURRENTDATE` command is evaluated to execute. You can see this if you run the `ps` command, AFTER it's executed. Notice in the output that it shows the value of current date rather than `$CURRENTDATE`.

```
$ CURRENTDATE=$(date +%Y%M%d.log)
$ tail -F $CURRENTDATE

$ ps -eaf|grep tail
saml      1171 13564  0 22:13 pts/4    00:00:00 tail -F 20130517.log
```

This issue you're encountering is typically why most server daemons such as Apache, Nginx, or Jetty log all the current date into a file named, `error.log`, and then this file is rotated to another name, such as `error_20130517.log` afterwards.

This allows you to monitor the `error.log` continuously using a command such as `tail -F error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you are looking for:

```
watch -n 60 'tail -n 30 /path/to/logfile-$(date +%Y-%m-%d.log)'
```

This refreshes the logfile for the current date every 60 seconds. 
Customize the n parameters to your liking.
Note the single quotes: These make the watch command evaluate the command every time instead of evaluating it once and providing output. I ran into the same problem myself and this worked perfectly for me. I don't think the current answer of "Well the big players don't like to hack around so they use logrotate" is an adequate solution if you're trying to debug a program that logs this way instead of the other way.

This is the quick and dirty way, but If you're developing something, make like the big players and use logrotate.